# Haxe Curl - Failed to load library : curl.ndll

Tags: curl, haxe

I used haxelib to install Haxe-Curl and run it on a project. However, trying to import or use the package gives me the following compiler error for neko:

> Uncaught exception - load.c(237) : Failed to load library : curl.ndll (dlopen(curl.ndll, 1): image not found)

flash returns different errors but similarly refuses to run. I'm relatively new to haxe but I can't find any evidence of this error online. Is this because haxe-curl expects a particular version of curl to be preinstalled on this machine? Am I doing something obvious?

The lib is in the project's xml file, and the import is based on the test code in the haxe-curl repo itself, so there's very little to show in terms of a minimal working example.

Answer (score 0):

As it is stated in the description of the library, it is only implemented for neko and php.

Going for the neko part: the best guess is that your compiler is misconfigured in some way or you didn't execute some initialization command of the library itself. (Of course there is also a chance the library is poorly written.)

Note: It is impossible to use curl in flash, it doesn't allow to load libraries.